# Opencv findContours System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv

I'm on Windows 7 in VS2008 C++ in a form application. When I try to use `findContours` (Opencv 2.4.2) I get a `System.AccessViolationException`.
Everything is ok with the "gray" image, it seems like the vector cannot be initialized by findContours.
Here is the code:

```
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
threshold(gray, threshold_output, threshDiff, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
imshow("input_img", gray);
findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use threshould_output instead of gray in findContours? How do you obtain gray?

Comment: There is no problem with the gray image, same code works perfectly on OS X.

Comment: Try OpenCV231 or older. (inlcudes,libs,dlls)